# How do i convert from milliseconds to seconds units to be shown in a Label?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code:

```
private void Form1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (leave == true)
            {
                if (e.Delta > 0)
                {
                    if (timer1.Interval < 5000)
                    {
                        timer1.Interval += 1000;
                        label2.Text = (timer1.Interval/1000).ToString();
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    if (timer1.Interval == 1000)
                    {
                        timer1.Interval -= 100;
                        label2.Text = (timer1.Interval / 1000).ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The original timer1 interval in the designer is set to 1000 milliseconds.
In the mouse wheel event i did that it will show in the label2 the untis in seconds.
And indeed when i move the mouse wheel up its slowing the timer and show it in seconds 1 2 3 4 5

The problem is with the second part i wanted that when its getting to 1 second or 1000 milliseconds if i will keep wheel it down it will show the units in 100 and change the timer1.interval in 100 units.

So in label2 if it was on 1 second so now i will see 900 800 700 600 500 un till 100.
And also the timer1 interval should be change to 900 milliseconds 800 700 600 untill 100.

When its get to 100 just stop there dont keep getting under 100.

The problem is with this part:

```
if (timer1.Interval == 1000)
                    {
                        timer1.Interval -= 100;
                        label2.Text = (timer1.Interval / 1000).ToString();
                    }
```

Its not working at all.

EDIT**

My code now:

```
if (leave == true)
            {
                if (e.Delta > 0)
                {
                    if (timer1.Interval < 5000)
                    {
                        timer1.Interval += 1000;
                        label2.Text = (timer1.Interval / 1000).ToString();
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                     if (timer1.Interval > 1000) {
                         timer1.Interval -= 1000;
                         label2.Text = (timer1.Interval / 1000).ToString();
                     }

                    else

                    if (timer1.Interval <= 1000 && timer1.Interval > 100)
                    {
                        timer1.Interval -= 100;
                        label2.Text = (timer1.Interval / (double)1000).ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
```

But now if i was at 5 seconds(5000 milliseconds) now i move the wheel back down its counting 5 4 3 2 1 0 and stop on 0

It dosent show under 1 ...0.9 0.8 0.7 as it did before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the check to:

```
if (timer1.Interval <= 1000 )
```

The timer interval will only be at `1000` once, before you subtract 100 from it and make it 900.  By checking for values `<= 1000` it will continue to work for lower values.

You might also want to check that the interval doesn't get too low and expand the check to be

```
if (timer1.Interval <= 1000 && timer1.Interval > 100)
```

To show times less than 1 second, you will need to make sure the division is by a floating point type, otherwise it will just show 0.  Dividing by an integer causes any fractions to be truncated

```
label2.Text = (timer1.Interval / (double)1000).ToString();
```

To reduce the `Interval` when it is higher than 1000, you need an extra check.  E.g.

```
if (timer1.Interval > 1000) {
    timer.Interval -= 1000;
} else if ( timer.Interval <= 1000 && timer.Interval > 100 )
    timer.Interval -= 100;
}
```

Comment: Steve your changes are working for the bottom part but once im getting to 1 second and above i cant get down again. The maximum i can get is to 5 seconds ( 5000 milliseconds ) in the upper part. But if im on 2 3 4 or 5 seconds i cant change it down again. Why does is stay on the interval above 1000ms ? The upper part timer1.Interval < 5000 is the same i didnt change it. Only the bottom part.

Comment: @DoronMuzar The interval is only reduced when the interval is <= 1000.  You need to reduce it when it is higher as well.  I've added some extra logic to the answer.

Comment: Steve look please for seconds on my question updated it with the current code as i did it from your example. But now if i was on 5 seconds and move back down its doing 5 4 3 2 1 0 and hold/stop on 0. It dosent do from under 1 0.9 0.8 0.7 0.6 as it did before.

Comment: @DoronMuzar I would suggest debugging it and seeing what isn't quite right.